# How can I use a jquery array in asp.net, and reading values of array from asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I have an array in jquery, and I'm adding values on runtime to this array.After I will access this aray from asp.net page ie:
jquery:

```
var marker=[];
marker[0]='world';
marker[1]='sky';
```

asp.net:

```
string []values=new string[];
values[0]=marker[0];
values[1]=marker[1];
```

how can I do it, is there any way to access jquery veriables from asp.net pages

Answer (score 1):

you can store these values in a `hidden field` and read them in asp.net code behind

examples here :

[To get value set in javascript in code behind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409030/to-get-value-set-in-javascript-in-code-behind)

[Passing value from code-behind to Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656328/passing-value-from-code-behind-to-javascript)

**Edit**

you can pass this array to a `WebMethod` using ajax post

[JQuery AJAX post to asp.net webmethod never getting called](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529953/jquery-ajax-post-to-asp-net-webmethod-never-getting-called)

Comment: can I add array values to hidden field ?

Comment: yes , you can add them as string separated by commas or semicolons , and split them on server

Comment: I don't think so , I used it many times , I'll search for better ways and get back to u

Comment: I was looked the first link , but I don't use it because I don't know can I use the example free. I'm looking the second example thank you :-)

Comment: Can you remove the first link, I will use the hidden field :), because using static methods in asp.net, I can use another non static methods from static methods,[WebMethods] mus be a static method so ,ı can use them